# set named.conf forwarders to dhcp supplied dns ip?

Tags: bind

I run `bind9`/`named` on a CentOS7 machine that receives its ipv4-only config via DHCP, including a DNS/nameserver that resolves global and intranet hostnames.

The `bind9`/`named` on this machines has a zonefile to resolve a limited set of hostnames.

My desire is that the `bind9`/`named` when receiving a query/request will resolve directly for those limited set of hostames. For everything else I want it to resolve the request via  recursion/forwarding to the DNS/nameserver the machine was supplied with via DHCP (and which therefore is not a static ip)

I therefore **cannot** use this `/etc/named.conf` options

```
options {
  [....] 
  forwarders {
    8.8.8.8; // google
  };
  recursion yes;
  [....]
}
```

because I do not want to use google's `8.8.8.8` DNS server for those request, but instead the one which the machine itself would use and which was supplied via DHCP (i.e. which is set in `/etc/resolv.conf` )

How would could one instruct/configure the `bind9`/`named` service to resolve anything not resolveable via its zonefile by using the **systems DHCP supplied nameserver**?